# QGIS Exporting Layout as Blank PDF?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, export, pdf

I am trying to export my map layout in QGIS3.4.5 on OSX 10.14.

I've made the layout look exactly how I want it to look, but whenever I export to PDF, the PDF file is just a blank white page. The console gives me the message: "Export layout: Successfully exported layout", which is puzzling. When I export to TIFF and PNG, it gives me the same message, but no file is output.

The map I'm trying to make is really basic. I attached a screenshot here, in case there is something I am missing. It's just a hillshaded DEM and some symbolized X-Y data. I would think this would be an easy thing to fix, but all the solutions to similar problems I've seen on here have not worked.

Solutions I have tried:

- Reduce the file size of the rasters by clipping them to my study area
- Lower the DPI
- Export to image
- Remove ESRI basemaps from QuickMapServices.

[image: Site Map]

Comment: As a workaround, have you tried exporting directly from the map canvas? You can add the grid and north arrow as "decorations," but you'd lose the legend.

Comment: I tried that and it worked. Thanks! But I also created a new a layout and exported the map without any issue. I think it may have had something to do with the fact I had used a custom page size, instead of A4.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue on a layout with custom dimensions. Then I noticed that in the menu where I specified my layout dimensions, there was a box labeled "exclude page from exports" that was checked for some reason... After I unchecked it, I was able to export my layout successfully.

[image: exclude page from exports]

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment - this was driving me nuts! For some reason, I think this flag must turn on automatically when setting an unusual custom page size (which I was also doing in my case)